# A message from a new baker

Tags: cipher

There is a pie stuck to the ceiling, written in the pastry is...

> 63, 26, 29, 60, 29, 60, 41, 79, 19, 29, 57, 60, 63, 54, 66, 16, 60, 63, 29, 48, 44, 26, 16, 57, 16, 51, 38, 16, 4, 60, 16, 7, 16, 44, 29, 10, 16

What is the author trying to say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This decodes to

> This is my first question here, please be nice.

Welcome to Puzzling SE!
A note for the future: Please read [this helpful post](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do) for help on what to do (and NOT to do) when setting this type of puzzle. There's not much more here than a peremptory "here's a code, solve it" challenge, which does not an interesting puzzle make.  Hope to see you around, and if you read through some of the better received puzzles here hopefully your next one will benefit from the experience!

Explanation:

> This is a substitution cipher, with 16=E, 60=S, 63=T, 57=R, 44=N, 26=H, 41=M, 79=Y, and so on.  After noticing it isn't a simple A=1/Z=26 code (including mod26 forms), but seeing the result of that transposition has many of the earmarks of common substitution ciphers, it wasn't much more work to find the frequent letters. A couple educated guesses later and it's solved.

Comment: I shall take a look at those links before I ask another, thanks. However, you appear to have missed out the clue left in the question in tour answer. You shouldn't need to guess or look at frequent letters, there is a more direct way :)

Comment: Ah. The x3 thing, with perturbations. Yes, I missed that. Clever :)

Comment: The clue was meant to lead to ceil(letter * pi), I didn't even know it could be worked out by other means!

Comment: Even more clever. But unclued, so nothing motivating someone to try it... hence, solved by other means. If you want people to get something like that, you need something more than a reference to pie.